# GWT Unable to add background image to Simple Panel

Tags: gwt

I have a `SimplePanel` and I am trying to set it's background image programatically but below method doesn't work. Why?

```
this.coverImage.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundImage("images/veg.jpg");
```

For :

Style:

```
.coverImage{
  width:400px;
  background-color:#e5e5e5;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:190px;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

However, adding background-image: `url("images/veg.jpg")` works.

Comment: <g:SimplePanel  addStyleNames="{style.coverImage}" ui:field="coverImage">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it ;)

```
this.coverImage.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundImage("url('images/veg.jpg')");
```

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO. :-P